# Python2.7, Tkinter: instance has no __call__ method

Tags: tkinter, calendar

I've searched high and low and haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong now. I am trying to get the date selected in my calendar to appear in the corresponding entry field. But I get this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\NAME\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "/Desktop/scripts/Test.py", line 503, in show_Calendar2
    self.initialtext2.set(calendar(format_str='%02d-%s-%s'))
AttributeError: Calendar2 instance has no __call__ method
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8483bc3e40c1a63c335aa73b22e77aa5) is a link to the script with the Calendars in it. The calendars work and will print the date selected when it's clicked but I can't seem to figure out a way to get the selected date to enter into the entry field next to each calendar button in the main window.

I tried using:

```
self.initialtext2.set(calendar.get_date(format_str='%02d-%s-%s'))
```

and a few other variations but I'm at a loss as to how to do this. Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instance has no __call__ method` means you are doing something like this:

```
class SomeClass():...

# create instance of the class:
something = SomeClass()

# try to call the instance:
result = something()
```

If `SomeClass` hasn't defined `__call__`, you'll get the error you are getting.

The error is almost coming from this statement:

```
calendar(format_str='%02d-%s-%s')
```

If you look two lines before that in the code you linked to, you'll see this:

```
calendar = Calendar2(self, format_str='%02d-%s-%s')
```

Thus, `calendar` isn't a function, so you can't call it.

Comment: @TheHoff: when you do `foo(...)`, you are _calling_ a _function_ named `foo`. So, when you do `calendar(format_str...)`, you are _calling_  a _function_ named `calendar`. However, `calendar` isn't a function, so you can't call it.

Comment: but calendar is:

    `calendar = Calendar1(self, format_str='%02d-%s-%s')`

So calendar should call the function Calendar1 right?

Comment: @TheHoff: no, because `Calendar1` isn't a function, it's a class. You are creating an instance of `Calendar1` and assigning that to the variable `calendar`. `calendar` is not an object of type `Calendar1`. This is no different than how `foo = Frame()` creates an object of type `Frame` and assigns that to `foo`.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand now. I changed `def show_Calendar1(self):` to this: `Calendar1(self, format_str='%02d-%s-%s') self.wait_window(Calendar1) # wait for the toplevel to quit self.initialtext1.set(self.Calendar1(format_str='%02d-%s-%s'‌​))` and it's not giving me the no call method error anymore but it's still not entering the date selection into the entry field.

Comment: @byanoakley I seem to be on the right track but I must be missing something. i changed the `set.initialtext` for Calendar 1 and 2 to `self.initialtext2.set(Calendar2.get_date.get())` but I get `'function' object has no attribute 'get'` returned. Somehow I have to get the date that appears when selected into my entry fields. In the calendars the return should be under `def get_date` with `self.full_date` but how do I pull it into the `self.initialtext2.set(Calendar2.get_date.get())` line?

Comment: Just in case anyone visits this in the future. The follow on question regarding getting the selected date into the entry field is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277666/pythontkinter-calendar-selection-into-entry-field